# Why is the positive lookahead in my pcregrep Regex not working?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, pcregrep

I wrote a Regex using pcregrep, and everything behaved as expected until I added a positive lookahead.

**Scenario:**

I have the following text file:

```
a
b
c
a
c
```

**Goal:**

I want to use a Regex with pcregrep to return a line containing `a` and a line containing `c` with a line containing `b` between them that is *not* captured. So it would capture the first three lines (`a`, `b`, `c`) and return the first (`a`) and third (`c`) line. It would *not* capture the fourth and fifth line because there is no `b` line between them. So the output would be:

```
a
c
```

**What I've tried**

If I run `pcregrep -M 'a\nb\nc\n'` (**command 1**), this captures and returns:

```
a
b
c
```

as expected. So I now want to modify this to capture the `b` line with a positive lookahead. I tried this: `pcregrep -M 'a\n(?=(b\n))c\n'` (**command 2**). However, this returns nothing.

**My question:**

Why does **command 2** not return the expected output, where **command 1** does? How can I return the desired result? I know there are ways to do this other than `pcregrep`, but please note that I want to use `pcregrep` because I'll be extending the functionality to solve similar problems.

Comment: Keep in mind, that when using a lookahead, you do __not match__ the characters in the lookahead. You only assert (without matching the character) that the lookahead pattern is there. You _still have to __match__ the entire pattern_, and again, the lookahead does __not__ match, only asserts.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Understood, thanks for that. So I'm trying to use a non-capturing group now, like this: pcregrep -M 'a\n(?:(b\n))c\n'. This, however, still returns 'a', 'b', 'c'. Do you know how I can get it to return just 'a' 'c'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups with `-o` option:

```
pcregrep -M -o1 -o2 '(a\n)b\n(c)\n' file
```

```
a
c
```

**Details:**

- `(...)`: In regex it is used for capturing groups
- `-o1 -o2`: prints only capture group #1 and #2

---

Note that your regex `a\n(?=(b\n))c\n` won't work because lookahead is just assertion with zero-width match. Your regex asserts presence of `b\n` after `a\n` which is fine but it attempts to match `c\n` **right after** `a\n` and this is where matching fails.

Comment: Yes I have written in my answer that `-o` prints `only-matching` part of matched string and `-oN` prints capture group #N

Comment: Last clarification, what if instead of just having a single line with `b` in the middle, I wanted to have an arbitrary number of `b` lines? At the moment I just have `b\n`, but to have zero or more lines like that, I think I'd have to do `(b\n)*`, right? But I don't want the `b\n` inside the parentheses to be captured. How would I do that with the strategy you've given me?

Comment: ...would I have to consider it a capturing group as well, and then do `-o1 -o3` in order to ignore the middle one?

Comment: ...also how does the Regex engine treat it if you have nested parentheses like (a(abc)*) ? Would the outer one be -o1 and the inner be -o2?

Comment: 1. You can use a non-capturing group to keep group numbering same: `pcregrep -M -o1 -o2 '(a\n)(?:b\n)+(c)\n' f`. 2. For `nested parentheses` number starts at opening parenthesis.

Comment: one more question: if I want to capture a line that does not start with 'a', I've been able to do that with pcregrep -M '^[^a]'. However, if all my lines start with letters surrounded by quotes, like "a", "b", "c" rather than a, b, c, pcregrep -M '^[^\"a\"]' doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: You can use: `pcregrep -M '^"[^a]'`

Comment: What if I want to print a separator between the `-o` groups? For example: if `-o1` matches 'hello' and `-o2` matches 'world', I want to print "hello,world". Is it possible?

Comment: I knew how to do it.. it can be done with `--om-separator=","`

Answer (score 1):

> Why does command 2 not return the expected output, where command 1 does?
>   Because command 2 is a different expression

`(?=…)` is a ZERO WIDTH lookahead

what you specified is: I want an `a`, followed by a linefeed followed by a `b`followed by a linefeed. At that position I also want a `c` followed by a linefeed.

P.S. to just get the a and c maybe this will help?

`pcregrep -M 'a\nb\nc\n' | pcregrep -M 'a|c'`

Comment: Understood, thanks for that. So I'm trying to use a non-capturing group now, like this: pcregrep -M 'a\n(?:(b\n))c\n'. This, however, still returns 'a'\n, 'b'\n, 'c'\n. Do you know how I can get it to return just 'a'\n 'c'\n?

Comment: I've added a proposal in my answer @gkeenley

Comment: This does work! Could you explain the logic behind how the "|" works in that?

Comment: second `pcregrep` can be replaced by `grep -E '^(a|c)$'` but IMO using more than one command to achieve this is inefficient

Comment: @gkeenley the first pcregrep spits out to stdout. The pipe ("|") feeds the stdout as stdin to the second pcregrep.

Comment: @anubhava - Sure… But as I do not know pcregrep this is the best solution I could think of besides going to perl instead…